# How can I use a Knockout viewmodel inside a server loop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

I want to use Html helpers and Knockout to create a seamless transition of data from server to client, and then back to server again on postback.

My ViewModel has a few properties and then an array of items.  I need to know how I can iterate over my array in ASP.NET Razor while assigning my knockout bindings to individual elements in the array.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Fields.Count; i++)
{   
    <div name="customFormField" data-bind="with: Fields[@i]">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Fields[i].SqlDataType)
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Fields[i].SqlDataType, new SelectList(selectDataTypeOptions), new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: SqlDataType" })
        </div>
    </div>  
}
```

My ko javascript:

```
<script>
    function viewModel() {
        this.addField = function() {
            alert("wut");
        }
    }

    $(function (){
        var jsonModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        var mvcModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonModel);

        var customFormTemplateViewModel = new viewModel();
        var g = ko.mapping.fromJS(customFormTemplateViewModel, mvcModel);

        ko.applyBindings(g);
    });
</script>
```

When I browse the page, the only elements rendered are the `<div name="customFormField" data-bind="with: Fields[x]"></div>` elements, neither the form-group div inside it nor the label/listbox are created on the page.

There are no binding errors from KnockoutJS.

If I remove the `data-bind="with: Fields[@i]"`, the other elements render properly, so it must be something about trying to bind to an element in an array that's making this go sideways, but I haven't been able to figure out what.

**Edit:** Here's the Html that is output from this:

It's interesting because if I inspect the DOM with chrome's inspector, it doesn't show anything inside each `customFormField` div, but in the source it does have the elements inside.  It's outputting the System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem in each item, but I think I just made my `SelectList` wrong.

```
    <div name="customFormField" data-bind="with: Fields[0]">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Fields_0__SqlDataType">SqlDataType</label>
            <select class="form-control" data-bind="text: SqlDataType" id="Fields_0__SqlDataType" multiple="multiple" name="Fields[0].SqlDataType"><option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
</select>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div name="customFormField" data-bind="with: Fields[1]">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Fields_1__SqlDataType">SqlDataType</label>
            <select class="form-control" data-bind="text: SqlDataType" id="Fields_1__SqlDataType" multiple="multiple" name="Fields[1].SqlDataType"><option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
</select>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div name="customFormField" data-bind="with: Fields[2]">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Fields_2__SqlDataType">SqlDataType</label>
            <select class="form-control" data-bind="text: SqlDataType" id="Fields_2__SqlDataType" multiple="multiple" name="Fields[2].SqlDataType"><option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
</select>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div name="customFormField" data-bind="with: Fields[3]">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Fields_3__SqlDataType">SqlDataType</label>
            <select class="form-control" data-bind="text: SqlDataType" id="Fields_3__SqlDataType" multiple="multiple" name="Fields[3].SqlDataType"><option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
</select>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div name="customFormField" data-bind="with: Fields[4]">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Fields_4__SqlDataType">SqlDataType</label>
            <select class="form-control" data-bind="text: SqlDataType" id="Fields_4__SqlDataType" multiple="multiple" name="Fields[4].SqlDataType"><option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
</select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Edit 2:**  This example is showing when I tried the `text` binding, but I've tried it both ways.

**Edit 3:**  I copied the output Html into another place on the page, and it didn't render that either, until I removed the `data-bind="with: Fields[n]"` from the containing div, so the problem seems to be there.  However, if I remove that from the parent in the actual file, I get a binding error from `data-bind="value: SqlDataType"`

Comment: Does `data-bind="with: Fields[i]"` work?  What's the [@i] bit? Also, what does Fields[i] compile into in the HTML?

Comment: It seems to work, i.e. there's no binding error.  Since it's just a with it's not supposed to show anything itself.  The @i is razor syntax to refer to the server loop iterator that it's inside.  I'll edit in the output.

Comment: So I'm pretty sure that "with: Fields[]" is not working, although it outputs everything properly (e.g. `with: Fields[0]`, `with: Fields[1]` etc.), and doesn't throw binding errors, I think it doesn't like the index in the binding.

Comment: What is g right before you apply bindings.